# OBJ model cannot be loaded yellow alert :Unexpected line: “<!DOCTYPE html>”

Tags: vue.js, loader

I encountered the same problem as him, I tried to solve it, but obviously there was no way, OBJ model cannot be loaded.

[link](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/uncaught-error-three-objloader-unexpected-line-doctype-html/8604/9)

> View: The screen shows yellow alert: Unexpected line: “<! DOCTYPE html>”,
>   The screen is displayed normally, but the model cannot be loaded

[image]

**my code: Model path**

[image]

```
//addOBJ
    loader() {
      let mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
      mtlLoader.setResourcePath("/models");
      mtlLoader.setPath("/models");
      mtlLoader.load("rhinoceros-Psychedelic.mtl", materials => {
        materials.preload();

        let objLoader = new OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.setPath("/models");
        objLoader.load("rhinoceros-Psychedelic.obj", object => {
          let mesh = object;
          this.scene.add(mesh);
        });
      });
    },
```

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console to see what requests are being made. It looks like whatever the request is, the result is an HTML document instead of your `.obj` file. That or your `.obj` file actually contains HTML

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question to explain what you're trying to do. Also, it is preferred that you include a short snippet of the code (in this case your loader function) in the question, rather than screenshots.

Comment: ok Thanks for reminding, First use

Answer (score 1):

thank u , My problem has been solved :joy:

**path +/**

```
mtlLoader.setResourcePath("/models/");
mtlLoader.setPath("/models/");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your loader is attempting to load an object from a URL that is failing. The `<!DOCTYPE html>` indicates that the URL is returning HTML, probably to display an error.

Go to your **Network** tab in your browser's dev tools and look for the URL to the `.obj` file. Click on it and you should be able to see a preview of what the HTML error is saying. Most likely, the asset is no longer being hosted at that URL.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the URL of the .obj file after clicking Network table